# Django queryset, using a queryset in another query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Suppose I have `ReadRecord` where I store `when-user-read-something`. (something is a generic foreign key)

```
ReadRecord:
  object = GFK(object_id, content_type)
  user
  timestamp
```

I have a blog model

```
Blog:
  modified_at
```

I'd like to find if there is a blog in a set of blogs whose last_modified_at is greater than the timestamp. (there's a blog which a user needs to read)

```
#First I get all read_records for a user for the blog set. 

read_records = ReadRecord.objects.filter(
     content_type=ctype, object_id__in=object_ids, user=user)

# see if there's any new blog a user need to read
for blog in the_blog_set:

   if not read_records.filter(object_id=blog.id).exists():
       return True
   if read_records.filter(object_id=blog.id)[0].time_stamp < blog.modifed_at:
       return True

return False
```

Wonder if there's a better way of doing the query?

Something like

```
blog_set.filter(id=T(read_records[object_id] & modified_at > T(read_records[time_stamp])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this in one query, because you're using a generic foreign key rather than a real fk and Django can't convert that to a JOIN. But what you can do is get the blogs and the records in one go each, using `prefetch_related`, then iterate through.

```
read_records = ReadRecord.objects.filter(
         content_type=ctype, object_id__in=object_ids, user=user
    ).prefetch_related('object')
blogs_to_read = []
for record in read_records:
    if record.timestamp < record.object.modified_at:
        blogs_to_read.append(object)
```

Comment: Thanks, what would it look like if it were not GFK and a regular foreign key?

Comment: About the same, but you could use `select_related` rather than `prefetch_related`, which does a JOIN so only uses one query. Not a massive difference in this case.

Comment: ah ok.. does prefetch_related works on ValuesQuerySet?